# Getting radio button value from view to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have reviewed and tried the answers already given on this forum but nothing worked. So now I am sharing my issue here. I want selected radio button value from view to controller to do further action on the basis of selected radio button. But its not working, receiving blank result. My view and controller code is below

```
<form>
                                    <div class="inline">
                                        <input class="magic-radio" type="radio" name="conn_ty" value="12m" id="12m" checked />
                                        <label for="12m">
                                            12 month terms
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inline">
                                        <input class="magic-radio" type="radio" name="conn_ty" value="24m" id="24m"/>
                                        <label for="24m">
                                            24 month terms
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inline hidden">
                                        <input class="magic-radio" type="radio" name="conn_ty" value="36m" id="36m"/>
                                        <label for="36m">
                                            36 month terms
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

Contoller:

```
$connection_term = $this->input->post('conn_ty');
echo $connection_term;
```

Comment: How do you submit your form?

Comment: I like to mention here that I am able to get other fields data from viewer.  only can;t read radio button value. submitting form by Post Method

Comment: Solved. The issue was I was using extra form tag in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your view:

Use ***echo form_open($url);*** instead of form tag and create a submit button.

On your controller

```
$connection_term = $this->input->post('conn_ty');
echo $connection_term;
```

Comment: Solved. The issue was I was using extra form tag in my code. Thanks

Comment: welcome., Please accept so that others will  know., :)

Answer (score 0):

put this on your view

```
echo form_open('on controller which function u want to get value');
```

and you have to declare

```
$RADIO_VALUE = array('name' => 'radio button name','id' => 'radio button id');
```

don't forget

```
echo form_close();
```